# Hide DirectX namespace inside my namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, directx, abstraction

I want enable colors from DirectX::Colors in my program, but without giving out that DirectX is used, so i'm trying this:

```
namespace Colors
{
    using namespace DirectX::Colors;
}
```

I hoped it would allow me to use e.g. Colors::Blue, but it doesn't. How can i do it?

Comment: How would that avoid letting on that DirectX is being used?

Comment: @CarlNorum i just will not, but if there more rigorous way, it is only better.

Comment: Have you tried `namespace Colors = DirectX::Colors;` ?

Comment: @1nflktd i will accept your comment as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use namespace alias:

```
namespace Colors = DirectX::Colors;
```

and then `Colors::...`